# How do I get past level 35 of Mr/Mrs. Block Free?

Tags: android, mr-block-free

I'm stuck in level 35 of [Mr/Mrs Block Free](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.Wuzla.game.Block_AD). How can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

> 1. Move grey block on ground on the left hand side over one more to the left so it is sitting right in the corner.
>
>  2. Move red square in top left hand corner over one so it falls on top of the grey block and turn that red block to stone
>
>  3. Move the grey block that's on the ground underneath the stone you just turned to stone - move that to the right into the blue transmitter tunnel. When it arrives, immediately move it to the right hand corner on the ground. It should now be in the bottom-most right hand corner of your screen.
>
>  4. Move the grey block on the top left hand side (top left corner of screen) over one so it sits on top of the block you just turned to stone, and then move it into the pink transmitter tunnel. It will land right on top of the other grey block you have put there. Immediately move that upper grey block into the blue tunnel to its right.
>
>  5. That grey block will arrive in the middle of the screen in the right corner. move it to the left so it's next to the pink whirlwind dot, on the right hand side, so that it is in place for one of the red squares to fall on top of it. Move one of the red blocks there on top of this block, and immediately turn that block to stone. Use that same grey block that's there (underneath the one you just turned to stone) and move that to the left, drop it off the end of that layer and move it then to the right, into the pink transmission tunnel. It arrives on top of the yellow block on top right hand side of screen. Immediately move it over one move, so that it drops to the ground. Leave it there.
>
>  6. Move the yellow block to the left and move it over the grey block, into the blue transmitter tunnel.. It arrives in the middle of the screen, just to the right of the red block. Leave it there for now.
>
>  7. Go to the grey block in the top right corner of the screen, and move it through the transmitter tunnel to its right. It appears on the ledge just below the red and yellow blocks. Move that to the right, position it under the yellow square, and then move the yellow block into that square, and it turns to stone.
>
>  8. Move that grey block over one more time so it's right in the corner, underneath the red square.
>
>  9. Go to the bottom right hand corner of the screen, to that grey block, and move that left into the pink transmitter tunnel. It arrives in the middle of the screen - all you do is move it over to the right one move, so that it sits on top of the grey block, and then move the red block into place. Voila!

Source: [Android Forums.com](http://androidforums.com/android-games/323749-mr-mrs-block-walkthrough.html#post2648388)